# Como passar parâmetro numa route?

Tags: php, laravel, route

Eu tenho uma rotina simples de teste, que não está funcionando na parte final.
A ideia é consultar um banco de dados MySql e compor uma página com o resultado, o que funciona corretamente.

Clicando-se sobre um link de uma linha desta página composta, dados referentes à linha deverão ser exibidos.

Para isto, será necessário que o link passe seu valor para uma nova rotina de busca, a fim de se consultar novamente o banco de dados para coletar mais informações, uma vez que a lista obtida inicialmente traz somente dados resumidos.

Esta parte é que não funciona. Resulta no erro:

> Sorry, the page you are looking for could not be found.
>   NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 161:

O código das 'routes' para a chamada das páginas está assim:

```
<?php
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});
Route::get('usuarioLer','controllerUsuarios@pesquisar');//pesquisa todo o BD

Route::get('usuarioDetalhar/{nome}','controllerUsuarios@detalhar');//pesquisa um item no BD

Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function () {
});
?>
```

A 'rota' usuarioLer é a que funciona 100%. Esta rota, como anotado, chama a página controllerUsuarios.php e provoca o método pesquisar.

Um fragmento desta página php é:

```
public function pesquisar (){
    $listaUsuarios = DB::select
 ("SELECT * from usuarios INNER JOIN categorias ON 
usuarios.TabFKUsuariosCategoria = categorias.TabCategoriasID");
    return view('viewUsuariosLista')->with('listaU',$listaUsuarios);
}//metodo pesquisar
```

O código acima chama uma página 'view', através do return, que exibe o     resultado de todos os registros do banco de dados.

A página viewUsuariosLista.php está com o seguinte código:

```
<?php
echo <<<BLOCO1
<html>
<head>
    <!-- <link href="../public/css/app.css" rel="stylesheet"> -->

    <link href="assets/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">         
    <script src="assets/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

 </head>
<body>
<table class="table">
BLOCO1;
foreach ($listaU as $u){
echo "<tr>";
echo    "<td>".$u->TabUsuariosID."</td>";
echo    "<td>".$u->TabUsuariosNome."</td>";
echo    "<td>".$u->TabCategoriasDescricao."</td>";
echo    "<td><a href='usuarioDetalhar?nome=".$u->TabUsuariosNome."'>
<span     class='glyphicon glyphicon-search'></span></a></td>";
echo "</tr>";
}//foreach
echo <<<BLOCO2
</table>
<br />
</body>
<html>
BLOCO2;
?>
```

Repetindo, até aqui tudo funciona 100%.

Agora, vem o erro. Ao clicar no 'link' gerado pela linha

```
echo    "<td><a href='usuarioDetalhar?nome=".$u->TabUsuariosNome."'>
<span     class='glyphicon glyphicon-search'></span></a></td>"
```

ele provoca a chamada da 'route' usuarioDetalhar, passando para a variável 'nome' o nome do usuário clicado. A 'route', como demonstrado lá no alto e que repito aqui

```
Route::get('usuarioDetalhar/{nome}','controllerUsuarios@detalhar');//pesquisa um item no BD
```

não funciona, ocasionando o erro mencionado.

A página 'view' de nome viewUsuariosDetalhes.php existe, e seu código simples é

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Detalhes do Usuário <br />
<h3><?php echo($u->TabUsuariosNome);?></h3>
</h1>
</h1>
<ul>
<li>
<b>Categoria:</b><?php echo($u->TabCategoriasDescricao); ?>
</li>
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mauro, que bom que conseguiu resolver o problema com a ajuda do @rray, mas sugiro depois nomear suas rotas pois será muito melhor caso precise fazer alguma alteração futura, por exemplo:

```
Route::get('usuarioDetalhar/{nome}',['as' => 'UsuarioDetalhar', 'uses' => 'controllerUsuarios@detalhar']);//pesquisa um item no BD
```

Depois de uma lida sobre o [Blade](http://laravel-docs.artesaos.org/docs/master/blade), é uma mão na roda... Muito prático e deixa o código super limpo.

No link vc chamaria a rota passando o *nome* da seguinte forma:

```
<a href="{{ route('UsuarioDetalhar', $u->TabUsuariosNome) }}">
```

Comment: Qual a vantagem de passar um array na definição da rota? +1 pelo `{{ route(....) }}`

Comment: Bom, eu passo array porque são 2 parâmetros, um pra definir o  nome e outro para definir o controller@método. Não sei se tem como nomear a rota e informar o controller sem usar um array.

Comment: `Route::get('usuarioDetalhar/{nome}','controllerUsuarios@detalhar');` geralmente eu vejo assim, perguntei pq era curiosidade mesmo :)

Comment: Entendi, é pq vamos supor q precise mudar o caminho "/usuarioDetalhar" para "/usuarioVisualizar". Teria que mudar tbm em todas as views. Já com ela nomeada não precisaria, pois continuaria chamando ela pelo nome, independente do cainho ter mudado. Acho q agr consegui explicar rs

Comment: Agora sim :D, funciona como alias.

Comment: iiiiiiisso!! rs

Answer (score 0):

Você deve definir o parâmetro na url com uma barra e não com interrogação.

Mude:

```
echo "<td><a href='usuarioDetalhar?nome=".$u->TabUsuariosNome."'>
```

Para:

```
echo "<td><a href='usuarioDetalhar/".$u->TabUsuariosNome."'>
```

Se a assinatura do método não tiver nenhum parâmetro, defina uma para receber o valor.

```
public function detalhar ($nome){ 
    $sentenca="SELECT * from usuarios INNER JOIN categorias ON usuarios.TabFKUsuariosCategoria = categorias.TabCategoriasID WHERE TabUsuariosNome = '".$nome ."'";
    echo $sentenca;
}
```

Comment: Realmente, isto elimina o erro de não achar a página, mas descobri que a variável 'nome', que deveria ser preenchida pelo clique nesse link, está chegando vazia à página-view 'usuarioDetalhar.php'. (Gostaria de retificar o que acabei de escrever. Queria dizer 'a variável nome está chegando vazia à página 'controllerUsuarios.php', onde existe o método 'detalhar'.

Comment: @MauroSimoes coloca o o código do `detalhar()`

Comment: O fragmento do código do método 'detalhar' é   

    public function detalhar (){
     $nome=Request::input('nome');
       $sentenca="SELECT * from usuarios INNER JOIN categorias ON usuarios.TabFKUsuariosCategoria = categorias.TabCategoriasID WHERE TabUsuariosNome = '".$nome ."'";
   echo $sentenca; ?>

Comment: @MauroSimoes, faz o seguinte mude assinatura do método para `public function detalhar($nome){ ...` e comente o a linha `$nome = Request::input("nome");`

Comment: Agora o problema foi resolvido, após sua dica, mas acho que resultou em outro: SELECT * from usuarios INNER JOIN categorias ON usuarios.TabFKUsuariosCategoria = categorias.TabCategoriasID WHERE TabUsuariosNome = 'nome=Mauro Simões'. Estou vendo que a consulta está com o meu nome como busca, misturado ao nome da variável.

Comment: @MauroSimoes quando vc faz `echo $nome` aparece o que?

Comment: Acho que resolvi o problema: Na página viewUsuariosLista.php, na linha em que havia echo    "<td><a href='usuarioDetalhar?nome=".$u->TabUsuariosNome."'>
<span     class='glyphicon glyphicon-search'></span></a></td>";
echo "</tr>";  troquei por echo  "<td><a href='usuarioDetalhar/".$u->TabUsuariosNome."'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-search'></span></a></td>";
echo "</tr>";

Comment: Enfim, para ficar claro a todos que necessitam de ajuda como eu, a chamada funcionou quando eu tirei do código o pedaço  usuarioDetalhar?nome=   e o substituí apenas por uma barra, ficando assim usuarioDetalhar/